# How to capture Code::Blocks screenshot

Tags: desktop-environments, screenshot

I'm trying to make some notes of Code::Blocks with wxWidgets. I have a wxChoice box on the screen. With the list collapsed (i.e., unexpanded) I can get a screenshot of the form.

However, with it expanded (i.e., when I click on the choice box and the list is seen) the screenshot does not work. I tried ALT+PrintScreen as well as just PrintScreen alone. Nothing works.

Is this a restriction or is there a way around this?

My platform: Ubuntu 12.04, Code::Blocks 10.05

Thanks!

Here's the screenshot without the Choices expanded (the form is totally meaningless - it's only for proof of concept).

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to time it because the keyboard focus is (at that moment) fixated on the menu, so it does not recognize you when you press the Screenshot button (For me this needs fixing. Not very intuitive.).

For this cases I don't go far, I use the `screenshot` utility that comes by default with Ubuntu. Simply open it and:

[image]

Set the option that says **Grab after a delay of** to how many seconds you need to open the options menu you are building. The end result will be similar to any sub-menu, something like this:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Try Shutter.

> Shutter is a feature-rich screenshot program. You can take a
>   screenshot of a specific area, window, your whole screen, or even of a
>   website – apply different effects to it, draw on it to highlight
>   points, and then upload to an image hosting site, all within one
>   window. Shutter is free, open-source, and licensed under GPL v3.

To install Shutter, just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command(s) below:

```
sudo apt-get install shutter
```

<sup>Source:[Shutter](http://shutter-project.org/)</sup>

Comment: Many thanks for your inputs... It is indeed a nice program. However, it does not serve my purpose. It has the same problem. I cannot capture the screen with a wxChoice box exapanded. I even set the keyboard shortcut but I think this is not possible with Ubuntu. Thanks anyway!

Comment: The timing was the case... Many thanks for the shutter tool. Quite helpful!