# Problem with using gnome-screenshot in awesome

Tags: 12.04, awesome

I'm having problem with using gnome-screenshot in **awesome wm**.
Here's the **screenshot**.

[image: using gnome-screenshot]

I'm using **awesome wm** and my linux distro is **Ubuntu 12.04**.
I have no idea how to solve this and what causes this.

Btw, when invoking the command, in **Ubuntu 12.04** *account*, not in  **awesome wm**

```
gnome-screenshot -a
```

There's no error at all.

Comment: Try Shutter.  Look at my answer [Here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/298963/how-to-capture-codeblocks-screenshot/298968#298968)

Comment: thanks, yeah i know Shutter. But, i want to resolve that problem. :)