# Making a screenshot in Xfce

Tags: xfce, xubuntu

I've installed Xfce desktop and removed Ubuntu's default DE. It turns out that making a screenshot requires running a special application called ScreenShot instead of just pressing `PrtSc` button.

I wonder, how do I do a screenshot in the same way I did before by pressing `PrtSc` button?

Comment: That maybe because of the mix-n-match. A 100% Xubuntu install would have the Prnt Scrn bound to `Xfce4-screenshooter`. But it appears that the Ubuntu bindings are still in effect.

Comment: Try Shutter.  Its an excellent application. See My answer [Here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/298963/how-to-capture-codeblocks-screenshot/298968#298968).

Comment: @vasa1, I asked how to bind PrtSc with making a screenshot command.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Go to:

> XFCE Menu  -->  Settings  -->  Keyboard  -->  Application Shortcuts,

and add the `xfce4-screenshooter -f` command to use the *"PrintScreen"* key in order to take *fullscreen* screenshots.

Check [archlinux wiki / Screenshots](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Xfce#Screenshots) for more details or look at [Settings Manager](https://docs.xfce.org/xfce/xfce4-settings/start).

Here's what it looks like:

[image]

Comment: but can't add or remove any command from there.

Comment: It should work. On clicking add, a small window named _shortcut command_ will open. In the text box, add _/usr/bin/xfce4-screenshooter -f_, then press OK  and press the shortcut button.

Comment: there is no 'add' button -- http://makescreen.ru/i/65ede79a40e0ba10f5ba2a02ab1dc1.jpg

Comment: Looks like it is a newer interface. Maybe the feature to add new shortcuts will come later, not in your current version.

Comment: I personally recommend using the option -r instead of -f because it gives you the choice of taking the screenshot of whatever region you want.

Answer (score 3):

When using the keyboard>>Application Shortcuts to launch xfce-screenshooter, the program will not launch when a menu is opened on the panel.  It appears that when the panel's menu is opened, the keyboard shortcut doesn't fire.

However, if you want to capture the menu at the top, open a terminal session and execute the following one liner:

```
sleep 10s; xfce4-screenshooter -f
```

... then click on the menu and wait for the snapshot.  The one liner will wait for 10 seconds before grabbing a full screen image.  Adjust the sleep delay if you need more or less time to wait.

Comment: Ahh thanks - that's what the problem was - I was trying to get a screenshot of a panel menu!

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a Chromebook, you could also adjust key bindings, since there is no "print screen" key.

You could also just use the terminal commands "xfce4-screenshooter -w" to capture the terminal window, or use the -f flag to capture the whole screen and then edit in the image editor of your choice.