# gnome-screenshot returns gray image

Tags: gnome, 13.04

I'm having this problem since I got Ubuntu 13.04 (few weeks ago). At random times, when using gnome-screenshot, I get a gray image. It doesn't work until I restart my computer. I've tried getting GNOME 3.8 (it was a very bad idea), but it didn't solve the issue. Some other applications that capture screenshots (Screencloud) have the same issue. [Here's the gray image I'm getting.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EK1PH.png)
I've searched everywhere, but I couldn't find an answer.

My specs: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 09) RAM:2GB Type of computer:Laptop.

Comment: Can you let us know your configuration. What Graphics Card, how much RAM, type of Computer. The reason I ask is because it could be the wrong or corrupted Graphics driver.

Comment: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 09)
RAM:2GB
Type of computer:Laptop. @SimplySimon

Comment: @MarioErmando, when providing additional information it's better to add it into your question rather than as a comment.

Comment: Do you know what driver is being used?

Comment: I guess it's i915 @SimplySimon

Comment: You can find out by clicking on System Settings>Details>Graphics for more details of your Graphics card and driver. I do not have much experience with the i915 Graphics Card as I have never had a problem with the Intel Card in this laptop.

Comment: Take a look at [Shutter](http://askubuntu.com/questions/298963/how-to-capture-codeblocks-screenshot/298968#298968), it might help.

Comment: Nope.... @Mitch

Comment: So shutter in installed, and does the same thing?